# On a new ASP.NET Core hosted site, why does changing ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to any custom value cause hosting failure locally, without error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

If I go through these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio 2022
2. Create a new Blazor WebAssembly project (I don't think the template matters, any ASP.NET Core-hosted site would be the same).  Run the server self-hosted https profile using `dotnet run` and see that the host starts and the browser shows the default Blazor site.
3. In the LaunchSettings.json for the server self-hosted https profile, change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to any custom value like "Foo"
4. Run the site host using `dotnet run`

Expected: The host should start and the browser should show the site exactly as before.  It should use the settings in appsettings.json but of course not those in appsettings.Development.json.

Actual: The host seems to start, but the browser gets a 404 error.  It seems like the host never sees the request.

Why won't the ASP.NET host serve up a page when the environment is anything other than "Development"? I must be missing some piece that needs to be configured or removed? (I removed UseHsts, UseWebAssemblyDebugging, and UseHttpsRedirection to be sure, but it didn't help.)

The above is a minimal example I was able to reproduce from scratch--of course, I have my own site where I want to use alternative ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT values (which seems [explicitly allowed in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-by-setting-an-environment-variable)) that I will apply this answer to.

Here's a [GitHub repo that demostrates the problem](https://github.com/szalapski/BlazorAppEnvText).  The README.md file reiterates the above.  How can I make this work with an arbitrary environment name?

Comment: Can you share your configuration?If you are using `Foo`,it will use appsettings,Foo.json.Without setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ,will you get 404 error?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, it will be ignored. (I tried it both ways).  I'll add a Git repo. but the reproduction of it is easy.

Comment: In MVC sites this is often because the startup routine has copped some internal error, tried to redirect you to an error page, not found the error page, and then surfaced _that_ error as a 404. It is... unhelpful. I'm not familiar with Blazor so am not sure whether it would follow the same pattern.

Comment: Added link to example repo.

Comment: @TomW, good thought, but I don't think I have any error redirection at all.  I get a 404 with no redirection in Chrome's Network tab.  Mind looking at the repo if you have a moment, to see if I'm missing anything?  https://github.com/szalapski/BlazorAppEnvText

Comment: (I agree-I don't think this is really a Blazor problem, as we never get anything on the client, so Blazor never starts).

Comment: For a Asp.Net core web project every thing works as you expect. That's must be Blazor sort of thing! So I recommend removing this part from the question :(I don't think the template matters, any ASP.NET Core-hosted site would be the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 7+, it seems the way to do this is a bit simpler than the .NET 6 answer that /u/scharnyw gave.  For .NET 7 and above:

`builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();`

Answer (score 4):

This is a [by-design behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43110#issuecomment-1206573745) of ASP.NET Core Blazor.

When debugging locally, the Blazor static assets are not placed under `{content root}/wwwroot/`, which is the path where ASP.NET Core looks for static assets by default. So there is a workaround solution by Microsoft which is to place a `{application name}.staticwebassets.runtime.json` file alongside your assembly, which contains the actual path to the static assets (i.e. under the Client project). Then at runtime, it invokes some logic so the server searches for the static files under the actual path instead of`{content root}/wwwroot/`.

The problem is that by default, this workaround is only enabled when the environment is set to `Development`. You can see that [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/921f5417741ca8086bd67d437ad40a91575095a1/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L222). To get around this limitation, in .NET 6 and .NET 5, you can add the following lines before the call to `builder.Build();`

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) =>
{
    StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(ctx.HostingEnvironment, ctx.Configuration);
});
```

Note however this is not very secure, because your server will be potentially serving files from arbitrary locations. That's why it's enabled by default only for Development. You should probably use the above lines for debugging only.

This is not an issue when you publish the app though, because the publish process will copy everything to one output directory, including the Blazor static assets in `wwwroot/` of the Client project.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  Inspired by the Model T?  "You can use any value as the environment, as long as it's 'Development'".

Comment: This solution doesn't seem recommended in ASP.NET Core 7; it gives `Suggest using WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration instead of ConfigureAppConfiguration`.  Any idea of such an alternative?